# Applying custom functions with assignment for multiple Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have multiple Pandas DataFrames in a list. Each DataFrame contains about 300,000 rows and 20 columns.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, ..., dfn]
```

I would like to apply various functions for each DataFrame mainly for pretreatment purposes.
However, with functions that include assignment does not work neatly.

For additional context, I have written the original code regarding only a single DataFrame in the first place. Now I am trying to apply the code with numerous DataFrames.

To illustrate, below are my attempts on the matter:

### What works:

```
[df.drop([0], inplace = True) for df in df_list]
```

...which needs not 'explicit' assignment on `df_list` or `df`s. Quite straightforward.

### What doesn't:

Again, I am trying to apply custom functions and update each DataFrame without repetitive/redundant lines of code. For example, I have defined a function changing the order of columns:

```
def col_change(df):
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols = cols[:6] + [cols[-1]] + cols[6:-1]
    return df[cols]
```

At first, the for loop seemed to be a simple solution without any function, but eventually found out that the for loop does not change the original element's value, if I'm not mistaken.

```
for df in df_list:
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols = cols[:6] + [cols[-1]] + cols[6:-1]
    df = df[cols]
```

With further research, I have tried other ideas:

```
df_list[:] = map(col_change, df_list)
df_list = [col_change(df) for df in df_list]
```

with no avail, since the columns in a DataFrame such as `df2` does not change.

### And so:

As a somewhat unpleasant solution, I have resorted to the following lines of code:

```
df1 = col_change(df1)
...
dfn = col_change(dfn)
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without writing every DataFrame I have? Why won't the `map` function or the list comprehension work in this situation?

Also, could anybody give any advice on this workflow? I have a feeling that having this many separate DataFrames might not be the best...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd stuff these all into a single dataframe with an additional column to identify them, and do `groupby().apply()` operations.

Comment: @PaulH Simple yet effective. Thanks for the tip!